# Why do Oculus SDK Unity VR interactables cease to function when hand tracking is temporarily lost?

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine, sdk, oculus

I'm developing with the Oculus interaction SDK in Unity and I'm having trouble with hand tracking. All the interactables and grabbables work fine until I lose hand tracking. IFf I lose hand tracking while grabbing a grabbable object, all interactables stop working. Hand tracking returns as expected, but I can't use an poke interactables or grabbables.

I'm using a mix of poke interactables and grabbable objects with One Grab Transformers attatched. Each grabbable object has a HandGrabInteractable child. I'm just using the default "Grabbable" script with the SDK.

If I'm actively grabbing something (in this case a throttle) and I temporarily lose hand tracking (replicated by covering cameras with my other hand), all interactables fail to work afterwards. I get my hand tracking back as expected, but I can't grab or interact with anything. I should be able to reach back out and regrab the object I was interacting with before, or any other object for that matter.

Edit: I've also just noticed that the interactions only fail on the hand that was actively interacting with something when tracking was lost.

Comment: Sounds like something isn't reset correctly in that case - have you asked the makers of the SDK about this? If this is repeatable I would claim it is worth a bug report

Comment: @derHugo Just posted on the dev forums. Can't find any official bug report forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking at this stumped in the future: This only happens when running over the link cable in the Unity Editor. Building the app fixes this issue.